# How To Capture Cata From Looping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I have a problem with capturing data from looping like the code below :

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    r = requests.get('https://data.com/page='+str(x))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
    results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'title-black'})
```

how to save the data for each page loop?

Comment: How do you want the data saved? For a simple use case you could append the `results` to a list.

Comment: i want to dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list called `final_result`, and add each result into it during iteration:

```
final_result = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    r = requests.get('https://data.com/page='+str(x))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
    final_result.append(soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'title-black'}))
```

Then you can create dataframe and add `final_result` into it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final_result)
```